# Use a view model to pass two models into a view in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I am trying to use a view model to pass two models into a view. The other model already has data that I am trying to display in a table.
I would like to have another form on the same page that will be posted. When I load the page I get an error saying I tried to pass into the view a list of `Customer` instead of `Entities.Models.RQF`.

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        //Supplier = new HashSet<Supplier>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MinLength(2)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
}

public partial class ReqRFQ
{
    public ReqRFQ()
    {
        //Supplier = new HashSet<Supplier>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ReqRFQId { get; set; }
    public int? RequisitionId { get; set; }
    public Guid RequisitionNo { get; set; }
    public string RequisitionTitle{ get; set; }
    public List<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile FormFile { get; set; }
}
```

HTML markup:

```
@model Entities.Models.ReqRFQ

@{ 
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page"; }
    var Req = (List<Customer>)ViewData["Cust"];
    Layout = null; 
 }

<table class="table table-bordered" id="customerTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                FirstName
            </th>
            <th>
                LastName
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <th>
                PhoneNumber
            </th>
            <th>
                Company
            </th>
            <th>
                <a onclick="showInPopup('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","RFQ",null,Context.Request.Scheme)','New Transaction')" class="btn btn-success text-white"><i class="fas fa-random"></i> New Transaction</a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>   
       @foreach (var Req in Model.Customer)         
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Req.FirstName
                </td>
                <td>
                    Req.LastName
                </td>
                <td>
                    Req.Email
                </td>
                <td>
                    Req.PhoneNumber
                </td>
                <td>
                    Req.Company
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a onclick="showInPopup('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit", "RFQ", new { id = @Req.Customer.}, Context.Request.Scheme)','Update Transaction')" class="btn btn-info text-white"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> Edit</a>
                    <form asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="Req.Id" onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxDelete(this)" class="d-inline">
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Req.Id" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>                   
        }}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

C# code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexMethod()
{
    Customers = await _customer.GetAllAsync();

    ReqRFQ viewModel = new ReqRFQ();
    viewModel.ReqRFQId = 0;
    viewModel.RequisitionId = 1; 
    viewModel.RequisitionNo = Guid.Empty; 
    viewModel.RequisitionTitle = ""; 
    viewModel.Status = ""; 
    viewModel.Customer = new List<Customer>();

    var customers = _context.Customer.ToList();

    foreach (Customer customer in customers)
    {
        var eachCustomer = new Customer();
        eachCustomer.Id = customer.Id;
        eachCustomer.FirstName = customer.FirstName;
        eachCustomer.LastName = customer.LastName;
        eachCustomer.Email = customer.Email;
        eachCustomer.PhoneNumber = customer.PhoneNumber;
        eachCustomer.Company = customer.Company;

        viewModel.Customer.Add(eachCustomer);
    }

    // viewModel.Add(viewModel)
    // ViewData["Cust"] = Customers.ToList();
    // ViewData["BEELevelId"] = new SelectList(_context.BEELevel, "BEELevelId", "BEE_LevelId");
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the controller code as well?

Comment: Looks like you've tried a few things -- have you tried ViewData["Cust"] = viewModel.Customer; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `ViewModelDTO` that wraps both Models and then use the `ViewModelDTO` in the view:

ViewModelDTO.cs:

```
public class ViewModelDTO
{
    public List<Customer> Customer { get; set; }  
    public ReqRFQ ReqRFQ { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexMethod()
{
    ViewModelDTO viewModelDTO = new ViewModelDTO();
    viewModelDTO.ReqRFQ = new ReqRFQ();
    viewModelDTO.Customer = new List<Customer>();

    viewModelDTO.ReqRFQ.ReqRFQId = 0;
    viewModelDTO.ReqRFQ.RequisitionId = 1;
    viewModelDTO.ReqRFQ.RequisitionNo = Guid.Empty;
    viewModelDTO.ReqRFQ.RequisitionTitle = "";

    viewModelDTO.Customer = _context.Customer.ToList();
    return View(viewModelDTO);
}
```

Then use `ViewModelDTO` in the view:

```
@model Entities.Models.ViewModelDTO
```

This way you can use data from both models on the same page.

Hope this can help you.